# How do I associate a file extension with an application using a .desktop file (under linux)?

Tags: linux, desktop

I have a .desktop file which associates my application (mmxfer) with specific mime types, and this works fine. When I right click a media file it gives me the option to use mmxfer to open it.

But what if I want to associate a project with a specific file extension, say '.sply', which really just contains some data serialized from python and so doesn't have a unique mime-type?

My current .desktop file is below. What should I change to associate mmxfer with '.sply' files?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MMXfer
Comment=Convert music and video and transfer it to a portable player using mtp
Exec=/usr/local/bin/mmxfer %U
Icon=/usr/local/share/mmxfer/mmxfer.png
Terminal=0
Type=Application
Categories=Application;AudioVideo;
MimeType=application/ogg;
```

I missed out most of the mime types as there were dozens.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [create a MIME type](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/AddingMIMETutor) first.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30931/register-file-extensions-mime-types-in-linux/31836#31836) is helpful. Also take a look at XDG's [Shared MIME info database](http://standards.freedesktop.org/shared-mime-info-spec/shared-mime-info-spec-latest.html).