# How do I associate a custom MIME-type to my local application in the major browsers?

Tags: browser, cross-browser, mime-types, mime

I want to invent a new mime-type and associate it to a custom application in the browser to enable users to launch my app from a web page. The users of my secure web site are in a closed-environment, meaning this is not a general-purpose, mainstream application - I can configure their browser ahead of time.

[Spoon.net](http://www.spoon.net) does something very similar to enable launching virtualized applications using their mini-kernel plugin.

One of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6265717/how-to-start-up-a-desktop-application-in-client-side/6265845#6265845) alluded to this method, without details for how to accomplish it.

How do I achieve this in a cross-platform manner on Chrome and IE 8/9? Is there a way to do the mime-type association through browser extensions, either native or through [crossrider](http://www.crossrider.com)? How does an app like Adobe Reader or Apple Quicktime achieve this? I want to avoid touching the registry if possible.

What are the risks associated with this method? My site is an intranet web application secured with a certificate and trusted by my users. Any reason I should not go down this path?

**EDIT**: Apparently this can be achieved in Firefox by manipulating the [mimeTypes.rdf file](http://kb.mozillazine.org/MimeTypes.rdf).

**EDIT**: It looks like [JDIC](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/jdic_assoc/) is a Java-based mechanism that could be used for the same thing. Is there a similar non-Java construct? Maybe in Javascript?

Comment: I don't know much about this, but I've seen some apps use a custom url scheme, like callto: for skype That may be a simpler option?

Comment: Yeah, based on the question I linked it sounds like that is a custom protocol, requiring an associated app to be running when that url is followed. I was hoping to avoid that, instead let the browser / extension recognize a MIME-type and fire up the app. I'm trying to minimize client-side installation and resource usage if possible. Good suggestion, though!

Comment: Information about registering protocols can be found [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Register_protocol). This may be the route I go, but I'd really like to know how to do it with a custom mime-type.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like it can be done via a [registry change on windows](http://bitworking.org/news/Atom_Auto_Sub_How_To).

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.atom]
    @="atom_file"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\atom_file]
    @="Atom Syndication Program"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\atom_file\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\atom_file\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\atom_file\shell\open\command]
    @="\"C:\\AtomHandler\\handle.exe\" %1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\application/atom+xml]
    "Extension"=".atom"
```

[Further reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997545) on Windows...

And here's [how to do so on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30931/register-file-extensions-mime-types-in-linux).

> Use xdg-utils from [freedesktop.org Portland](http://portland.freedesktop.org/wiki/)

Answer (score 1):

I often want to associate a new file type with being a text file. The safest and quickest way of doing this is:

A. Create the file type in Registry if it doesn't already exist

- Windows -> Search for RegistryEditor -> Open
- Right-Click HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT -> New -> Key
- Name the key the same as the extension (e.g. .txttt)
- Click on the newly created key (e.g. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT -> .txttt) -> Right-click on (Default) in the right pane -> Modify -> Set to the following values:

> (Default) REGSZ txtfile

- Right-click on the newly created key (e.g. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT -> .txttt) -> New -> String -> Set to the following values:

> ContentType        REG_SZ        text/plain

- Right-click on the newly created key (e.g. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT -> .txttt) -> New -> String -> Set to the following values:

> PerceivedType REG_SZ text

B. Associate the file type with a default program

- Right-click on your file -> Open with -> Choose another app
- Check "Always use to open with this program"
- Select the default program

The new file type should open and preview in Windows Explorer with the default text editor program you selected.