# Does Google chrome support custom MIME types?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, cross-browser, mime-types

Does Google chrome support custom MIME types? Actually, I added our own MIME type in Windows Registry that Chrome should support. But, Chrome cannot read that.
 I have written one method in JavaScript. In that method m calling     `Navigator.MimeType["<customMimeType>"]` .
 If script is executed in Firefox it gives right result but for chrome this statement doesn't work. How can I create custom MIME type in Chrome?
 Is there any other way by which Plugins register their MIME type and Chrome detects that?
can anybody please provide good resource to build **plugin** (not extension) for chrome?

Comment: are you referring to [navigator.mimeTypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.mimeTypes)?

Comment: yes. Navigator.MimeType["<customMimeType>"]

Comment: On my machine the same java script when run on two different browsers give different result for  Navigator.MimeType.Length.
In Firefox length of MimeType array is 31 and for Chrome it's 23.
Means Chrome could not detect some types that can be detected by firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but to my knowledge there is no compatibility in this current version of google chrome. You could though use a standard MIME instead with the custom MIME.

Comment: how can I deal with this problem then?

Answer (score 1):

Using the standard MIME Type would be the best option rather than the customized one.Chrome does not support the customized MIME types.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined all type of parameters in registry in windows??

Please refer old post to define custom mime in windows [`link`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267546/how-do-i-associate-a-custom-mime-type-to-my-local-application-in-the-major-brows)

If you have missed last line

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\application/atom+xml]
    "Extension"=".atom"
```

here **.atom** is your type and **application/atom+xml** is your definition.

you have not defined you mime type name or definition so not able to judge on that, please define if the above does not help..