# XMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader() returns null

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, mime-types

I've created a custom MIME type called `application/x-mytype` with extension `.mytype` following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267546/how-do-i-associate-a-custom-mime-type-to-my-local-application-in-the-major-brows). Then, I created a file in my server named `test.mytype` and I'm trying to get it's Content-Type via `XMLHttpRequest` but it looks like the browser cannot detect it.

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://{myserver}/test.mytype", true);
xmlhttp.send(null);

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function (oEvent) {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
        var contentType = xmlhttp.getResponseHeader('content-type');
        console.log(contentType); // prints null

        if(contentType === 'application/x-mytype') {
            // never arrives here
        } 
    } 
};
```

If I look at my "file type" via Windows Explorer, I can see my custom type, so it is looking at Windows registries. Do I have to set anything else or browsers aren't supposed to identify my custom MIME type?

Comment: Try `'Content-Type'`

Comment: still no success @Bergi