# Is it possible to set icon for a custom file used by my app

Tags: qt, filesystems, installation

I would like to create and app using Qt which will use custom files. The app will be available on Windows, OS X and Linux.
The idea is to have a custom icon for my file type (e.g. when you install Adobe's Master Collection, .as, .fla, .ps, etc. files have they own icons).

As far as I know Qt only helps you with app icon. I did not find any kind of support for this kind of problem.

This seems to be an OS problem. Do I need to create scripts to run on app install? (I will be using Bitrock's install builder to provide installers)

How can I achive this behaviour on all OSs?

Comment: For Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1387769/create-registry-entry-to-associate-file-extension-with-application-in-c . For Linux: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30931/register-file-extensions-mime-types-in-linux

Comment: @PavelStrakhov So creating scripts is the only way? I thought that there may be other solutions.

Comment: Scripts are not necessary. You can create described registry entries and files and execute external commands using Qt.