# How I could create register file type and its icon using Qt Framework Installer?

Tags: linux, qt, frameworks, installation

Only for windows available to create register file type in Qt Framework Installer. Is there any ways to create register file type and its icon for Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux you can define new extensions in `/etc/mime.types`.
Then you need to have a `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications` for your program, that defines which MIME types it is connected to.

You might want to look at [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30931/register-file-extensions-mime-types-in-linux).

Comment: The Framework does provide such an option, however right now it's windows only... You will have to do as stated by cee. 

Check [Operations](https://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/operations.html) - You can use these commands to create the entries and the .desktop file.

Comment: I already defined new extensions but then how I include this in my application installer? When I using component.addElevetedOperation function in Create Operation, I try to use "Copy", but it has encountered an error "non-existent file" then I try to use "Move", but it displayed an error, "could not remove, unknown error". Then I try to put this on Installation finished but nothing happen.