# Creating Files Of Specific Type

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've written a shell script to create a number of files.  The user specifies the number of files and their file extension from the command line.  Here is my code

```
#!/bin/bash

NUM_FILES=0
FILE_TYPES=""
LOCATION=`pwd`

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "**** ERROR: You must specify the number of files you wish to create and (optional) the file types.\n\n"
    exit 1
fi

if [ ! -z $1 ]; then
    NUM_FILES=$1
fi

if [ ! -z $2 ]; then
    FILE_TYPES=$2
else
    FILE_TYPES=".tmp"
fi

n=$NUM_FILES

for (( i=1; i <= n; i++ )) 
do
    touch TEMP_FILE_$i.$FILE_TYPES    #Files created here - this is where my script needs work
    echo "Created file " TEMP_FILE_$i.$FILE_TYPES
done
```

My question relates to creating files of a specified type.  The second argument passed to the command line (`$FILE_TYPES`) is used to specify the extension that you want to use (txt, java, py, etc), but when I run the script Linux interprets all the files as type text and just adds the extension to the end of the file name.

eg, running `bash createFiles.sh 4 java` will result in four text files being created named `TEMP_FILE_1.java` but viewing the directory in Linux GUI shows the files of being type `text`.

How can I modify the shell script so that it will create files of the type specified?

Comment: I have just tested your script and it does exactly what you want. Can you try "ls -lh" in your console and show the output?

Comment: `if [ ! -z $1 ]; ...` is really asking for trouble.  Just write `NUM_FILES=${1:-0}; FILE_TYPES=${2:-.tmp}`

Comment: Hi William - I'm relatively new to shell scripting so can I ask why that statement is asking for trouble?  It's intended to check to ensure that the first argument passed to the script is not null

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Don't write the word "solved" in your question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "type" of regular file in Linux/Unix. You could register any of your own file extension to open files with specified extension with application you will chose.

Please look at answers for question: [Register file extensions / mime types in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30931/register-file-extensions-mime-types-in-linux)

Also to understand other *association mechanism* on Linux named "**Shebangs (#!)**", you could read this: [File extensions and association with programs in linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71504/file-extensions-and-association-with-programs-in-linux)

Answer (score 1):

Many tools look at actual file contents to determine file type (a'la [`file`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) utility). When you create empty files, theres no content that could be inspected to infer file type. So if you want to create files that would be recognized as particular type, probably you have to provide templates for every file type you support, and copy template contents to created files. For example, write some minimal Java program when creating `.java` files, write 1x1 pixel images when creating `.png` files etc.